# creating windows.forms.tabpage and storing in an array of objects doesnt work sometimes

Tags: powershell, winforms

I have created a gui using windows forms that allows you to click an 'add tab' button and it creates a new tab with a datagridview on it.

when I step through the tab creation code, it works every time but when I just run the program normally without a breakpoint, it seems to fail in adding the tabpage to the tabcontrol.

I get the error at step 1 in the paint function

```
'The property 'Controls' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.'
```

I'm guessing it might be that the control is being added to the tab too quickly since it works when stepping through it but i'm at a bit of a loss. I tried adding a sleep before and after, and that worked for a bit but now it always fails.

I left out the code where the initial tabpage, tabcontrol ($maintab) and datagrid are created but here is the code:

```
$tabCount = 0
$tabPage = @()
$datagrid = @()

function paint($form, $ctrl, $TablIndex, $name, $Text, $x, $y, $Width, $Height){
    try{$form.Controls.Add($ctrl)                             }catch{write-host step 1 error: $_}
    try{$ctrl.TabIndex = $TablIndex                           }catch{write-host step 2 error: $_}
    try{$ctrl.Text     = $Text                                }catch{write-host step 3 error: $_}
    try{$ctrl.name     = $name                                }catch{write-host step 4 error: $_}
    try{$ctrl.Location = System_Drawing_Point $x     $y       }catch{write-host step 5 error: $_}
    try{$ctrl.size     = System_Drawing_Size  $Width $Height  }catch{write-host step 6 error: $_}
    try{$ctrl.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0    }catch{write-host step 7 error: $_}
    $ctrl
}
function System_Drawing_Point($x,     $Y)     {$_ = New-Object System.Drawing.Point; $_.x     = $X;     $_.Y      = $Y;      $_}
function System_Drawing_Size( $Width, $Height){$_ = New-Object System.Drawing.Size;  $_.Width = $Width; $_.Height = $Height; $_}

function add-tab
{
    $tabcount ++
    $tabpage     +=  (paint $mainTab (New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabPage) $null ('tabpage' + $tabcount) $null $null $null $null $null )
    $datagrid   += (paint $tabpage[$tabcount] (New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView) $null ('datagrid' + $tabcount) $Null 10 10 ($width-60) ($height-800))

}
```

edit: I tried putting $maintab.refresh() right before creating the new tab, and that seemed to work for a bit but then now it stopped working again.

I also found out that you can pipe a command to wait-process to make powershell wait until a process has finished, so I tried this as well:

```
$maintab.refresh() | wait-process
```

Its not so bad when you can step through and find the problem, but when I step through it, it works every time!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I did wrong.  the way the script behaved led me astray but the solution turned out to be a very simple mistake.

upon creation of $maintab I had changed it to $script:maintab and then didn't change the $maintab within the add-tab function to $script:maintab.  the odd thing is that it would sometimes work and other times it wouldn't.  I still dont fully understand why it was behaving the way it did, but it works perfectly now.